# How to exclude filetype with autocmd to load language specific skeleton

Tags: vimscript, autocmd, filetype, filenames

I have the following in order to use a different template per language.  But I want English to be the default, if I don't specify `.en.adoc` in the filename.  But the `*.adoc,*.en.adoc` also picks up `*.fr.adoc` with the result that I get an English and French header in my new `*.fr.adoc`.  How can I avoid this?

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.adoc,*.en.adoc,~/translate/source/* 0r ~/.local/share/nvim/templates/skeleton.en.adoc

autocmd BufNewFile *.fr.adoc,~/translate/*/target/* 0r ~/.local/share/nvim/templates/skeleton.fr.adoc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that both `*.adoc` and `*.fr.adoc` match for `foo.fr.adoc`, so both autocmds are run.

The documentation for autocmd patterns is at [`:help file-pattern`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#file-pattern); looking at it, doing a robust "match *.adoc but not fr.adoc" is a bit tricky (though not impossible). Personally, I would opt for just an `if`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.adoc
            \  if bufname('')[-8:] is# '.fr.adoc'
            \|   :0r ~/.local/share/nvim/templates/skeleton.fr.adoc
            \| else
            \|   :0r ~/.local/share/nvim/templates/skeleton.en.adoc
            \| endif
```

If you have a lot of skeleton files, you can you look it up in a map `let s:skel_files = {'fr.adoc': 'skeleton.fr.adoc'}` etc. but for just two, an `if` should be fine.

Comment: Thank you!   Yes I could see the reason, but just not the proper solution.  Much appreciated!